# Angular universal rendering issue

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have an issue via Angular universal. When I do the first request (http://localhost:4200) I've got the Home page, but when I'm trying to get another page (http://localhost:4200/account) I've got the Home page to, after that my app render correct component but I need to get correct page on the first request, what I'm missing?

(Angular Universal don't render routes)
Angular 10, Angular-universal (nodejs, express.js) - 10

Comment: Without any code sample that's hard to tell. Also what backend technology are you using? ASP.NET Core, Express.js?

Comment: The default port for an Angular Universal app (ExpressJS) is `3000` did you serve the app with `ng serve`? If so, you are not running the server-side rendered app...

Comment: @Pieterjan Express.js, unfortunately, I can't provide an example (

Comment: @GuerricP no, im run     "dev:ssr": "ng run frontend:serve-ssr", (npm run dev:ssr)

Comment: try localhost:3000 then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by fixing CanActivate in the routing config
By default, I use localStorage for saving auth info, if I have not info about auth in the localStorage navigate to the home page, the server always navigates to the home page but in the browser, I have that info